# Reconciling convolution, fft and manual DFT results

Tags: signal-processing, fft, octave, convolution

In Octave, I am playing with signal processing primitives, attempting to reproduce the convolution theorem in multiple ways: that convolution in the time domain is equivalent to point-wise multiplication in the frequency domain.

I consider three routes to reconstruct the original signal:

1. The `fft` and `ifft` functions
2. The `conv` function
3. A manually constructed DFT matrix.

I am attaching my working code, and the output, glad for inputs on where the bugs may be located.

```
N = 512;                  % number of points                                   
t = 0:N-1;                % [0,1,2,...,N-1]                                    
h = exp(-t);              % filter impulse reponse                             
H = fft(h);               % filter frequency response                          
x = (1+t) .* sin(sqrt(1+t)); % (input signal of our choice)                    
                                                                               
y1 = conv(x,h,"same");    % Direct convolution                                 
y2 = ifft(fft(x) .* H);   % FFT convolution                                    
                                                                               
T  = transpose(t) * t;                                                         
W  = exp(j * 2*pi/N * T); % DFT matrix                                         
y3 = (x * W .* H) * W/N;       % "Manual" convolution                          
                                                                               
lw = 2                                                                         
                                                                               
plot(t,                                                                        
    x,         ";orig;",                      "linewidth", lw+1,               
    y1,        ";conv;",   "linestyle", "--", "linewidth", lw,                 
    real(y2),  ";fft;",    "linestyle", ":",  "linewidth", lw,                 
    real(y3),  ";manual;", "linestyle", "-.", "linewidth", lw)                 
                                                                               
set(gca, "fontsize", 20, "linewidth", lw)
```

[image]

1. In the first case (yellow), I am able to reconstruct the signal, but the scaling is not right (in fact the scaling is wrong in every case).
2. In the second case (red), it looks like the result is shifted, and half of the signal is lost.
3. In the third case (purple), I get something that's equivalent to `fft` but flipped horizontally.

Comment: There are several flaws: 1) you are comparing the convolution of `x` with `h`, to `x`: why do you expect the same amplitudes? 2) the `"same"` option doesn't do what you think it does. `y1 = conv(x,h); y1 = y1(1:N);` gives the expected result. 3) one of the two `W` has to be transposed-conjugated: `y3 = (x * W' .* H) * W/N;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issues:

1. Your definition of the kernel is not right. `conv` expects the origin of the kernel to be in the middle of the array (at floor(N/2) + 1), so your `t`, for the purposes of building the kernel, should be `t-floor(N/2)` (this puts the 0 at the right location). Also, the kernel should be normalized to avoid changing the signal strength with the convolution. Just divide `h` by its sum.
2. But now, `H = fft(h)` will be wrong, because `fft` (and the DFT) expects the origin to be on the first element of the array. Use `ifftshift` to circularly shift the kernel array to put its origin on the first element: `H = fft(ifftshift(h))`.
3. For the manual DFT, you use the same matrix for the forward and the inverse transforms. You need to conjugate transpose the matrix to compute the inverse transform: `y3 = (x * W .* H) * W'/N`.

This is my corrected code (also some changes in the plotting to make it compatible with MATLAB):

```matlab
N = 512;                  % number of points
t = 0:N-1;                % [0,1,2,...,N-1]
h = exp(-abs(t-floor(N/2))); % filter impulse response (this definition is symmetric around the origin, for a causal filter set the left half of h to zero)
h = h / sum(h);           % normalize
H = fft(ifftshift(h));    % filter frequency response
x = (1+t) .* sin(sqrt(1+t)); % (input signal of our choice)

y1 = conv(x,h,"same");    % Direct convolution
y2 = ifft(fft(x) .* H);   % FFT convolution

T  = transpose(t) * t;
W  = exp(2j*pi / N * T);  % DFT matrix
y3 = (x * W .* H) * W'/N; % "Manual" convolution

lw = 2;

clf
hold on
plot(t,x,        "displayname", "orig",                      "linewidth", lw+1)
plot(t,y1,       "displayname", "conv",   "linestyle", "--", "linewidth", lw)
plot(t,real(y2), "displayname", "fft",    "linestyle", ":",  "linewidth", lw)
plot(t,real(y3), "displayname", "manual", "linestyle", "-.", "linewidth", lw)
legend
```

Comment: *"Note that with this definition, h will also be symmetric around the origin, which is a nice property"*: not necessarily. He has designed here (I guess on purpose) a causal impulse response with an exponential decay. By definition a causal impulse response is zero before t=0. So nothing should be shifted here.

Comment: @PierU That's fine. The origin of the kernel should still be in the middle of the array for `conv` with `"same"`.

Comment: That's precisely why `"same"` is not the right option to use here. The right option is `"full"` (which is the default), which assumes that the origin of the kernel is on the first sample. And since the result is longer than the input array, a selection is needed afterwards.

Comment: @PierU That is another way to accomplish the same thing. Feel free to write an answer.

Comment: Thanks, your explanations on how the filter should be set up and what the fft expects are helpful.

Answer (score 1):

(just transforming my comment into an answer)

There are several flaws:

1. you are comparing the convolution of `x` with `h`, to `x`: why do you expect the same amplitudes?
2. the "same" option doesn't do what you think it does. `y1 = conv(x,h); y1 = y1(1:N);` gives the expected result.
3. one of the two W has to be transposed-conjugated: y3 = (x * W' .* H) * W/N;

Corrected code:

```
N = 512;                  % number of points                                   
t = 0:N-1;                % [0,1,2,...,N-1]                                    
h = exp(-t);              % filter impulse reponse                             
H = fft(h);               % filter frequency response                          
x = (1+t) .* sin(sqrt(1+t)); % (input signal of our choice)                    
                                                                               
y1 = conv(x,h); y1 = y1(1:N);   % Direct convolution                             
y2 = ifft(fft(x) .* H);   % FFT convolution                                    
                                                                               
T  = transpose(t) * t;                                                         
W  = exp(j * 2*pi/N * T); % DFT matrix                                         
y3 = (x * W' .* H) * W/N;       % "Manual" convolution                          
                                                                 
lw = 2                                                                         
                                                                               
plot(t,                                                                        
    x,         ";orig;",                      "linewidth", lw+1,               
    y1,        ";conv;",   "linestyle", "--", "linewidth", lw,                 
    real(y2),  ";fft;",    "linestyle", ":",  "linewidth", lw,                 
    real(y3),  ";manual;", "linestyle", "-.", "linewidth", lw)
```

Comment: Good point on #1 ...